# Слайдер Swiper не работает на сенсорных экранах

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, слайдер

На десктопах всё отлично работает, но на сенсорных экранах нет. Подключал так:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    iOSEdgeSwipeDetection: true
})
mySwiper.enableTouchControl ();
mySwiper.enableKeyboardControl();
mySwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
```

В [API](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) не могу разобраться, помогите, плиз

Comment: Вот тут все работает на сенсорных - http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WOo8Nfnyipo

Comment: Со стандартными параметрами не работает. Слайдер вертикальный, на весь сайт.

Comment: Хорошо. Еще раз. Демо-версии отсюда http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WOpAw_mLSpp у вас работают на сенсорных устройствах?

Comment: Я забыл внизу добавить див .swiper-scrollbar, в этом была моя ошибка. На поиск этой ошибки ушёл весь день.

Comment: Главное, что ошибка нашлась и понятно, откуда она взялась :)

Comment: Нифига не решилась проблема. Свайп на таче заработал, и шустро, зато все остальное нет. И с десктопа перестали остальные плагины работать:
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56825/discussion-between---and-labris).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было добавить в конце слайдера

```
<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
```

и в коде инициализации прописать следующее:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    IOSEdgeSwipeDetection: true,
    onTouchStart: function()
    {
        return false;
    },
    scrollbarDraggable: true,
    scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    scrollbarHide: true
})
```

Теперь всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

При инициализации слайдера таким способом:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    IOSEdgeSwipeDetection: true,
    onTouchStart: function()
    {
        return false;
    },
    scrollbar: {
        container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: false,
        draggable: true,
        snapOnRelease: true
    }
})
```

Тач работает, и шустро. Но всё остальное не работает. Видимо, конфликтует с jquery. В консоли выдаёт ошибку:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
```

Comment: Возьмите код с демки, там-то работает как надо.

Comment: Я с демки и брал. В HTML все теги проставлены. С десктопа всё отлично работает. Но не на сенсорных устройствах.

Comment: Собственно, вот тут более расширено описал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651521/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-swipe-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: Хорошо, еще раз. У вас работает демо-страница и на десктопе, и на сенсорных устройствах. А своя страница не работает. Значит, где-то ошибка при переносе или правке кода.