# Не могу решить проблему со слайдером Swipe на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Слайдер — весь сайт. На десктопе работает отлично, при стандартной инициализации.
Если добавляю параметры для сенсорных устройств — на планшете прокрутка работает отлично. И всё, больше ничего не работает, даже на десктопе. В консоли

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
```

Код инициализации слайдера:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    IOSEdgeSwipeDetection: true,
    onTouchStart: function()
    {
        return false;
    },
    scrollbar: {
        container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: false,
        draggable: true,
        snapOnRelease: true
    }
})
```

В плагинах:

```
'app/libs/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js',
    'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'app/libs/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    'app/js/common.js'
```

всё это минифицируется в script.min.js.
Если убрать секцию из инициализации

```
scrollbar: {
        container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: false,
        draggable: true,
        snapOnRelease: true
    }
```

Всё начинает работать, кроме скроллинга на сенсорных устройствах.

Comment: HTML я бы тоже добавил, в нем бывают ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема была в минификации файлов. Перенёс подключение swipe и его инициализацию непосредственно в HTML — всё заработало.